# What defines a discharged battery?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

In the case of an AA Alkaline battery, what actually happens inside the battery once it is fully discharged? What components of the battery change as we use it?

Comment: I think perhaps discharged is a highly relative term in reference to the surrounding chemical environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what actually happens inside the battery once it is fully discharged?

Alkaline batteries use the [exchange of electrons from zinc to manganese dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_battery#Chemistry) to produce electricity

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\\
\ce{Zn (s) +2 OH- (aq)}& \ce{->}& \ce{ZnO (s) + H2O (l) + 2 e-}\qquad \text{(anode)}\\
\text{(high potential anode)}\quad \ce{2e-}&\ce{->[load][\ ]}&\ce{2e-}\quad\text{(low potential cathode)}\\
\ce{2MnO2 (s)+ 2e- + H2O (l)} &\ce{->}&\ce{Mn2O3 (s) + OH- (aq)}\qquad \quad\text{(cathode)}\\
\end{array}$$

typically a battery voltage would decline according to:

$$\mathscr{E} = \mathscr{E}^{\circ} - \frac{RT}{nF}\ln Q$$

but in alkaline batteries all of the products and reactants are solids, which without going into heavy detail of the thermochemistry means that $Q = 1$ thus $\frac{RT}{nF}\ln Q = 0$ which means cell potential remains fairly constant ($\mathscr{E} = \mathscr{E}^{\circ}$). But this is only in theory as we can see alkaline batteries do lose voltage:

[image]

This is partly because the internal resistance of the cell will increase with time meaning that for a given external load the total load will increase with time reducing current and apparent voltage. But even with [no load voltage drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_battery#Voltage)s, the the zinc oxide will dissolve in alkaline medium meaning the reactions depart from ideal equations:

$$\ce{ZnO (s)  ->[+ H2O (l)] Zn(OH)2 ->[+2OH- (aq)] [Zn(OH)4]^2-}$$

this is not to say that $\mathscr{E} = \mathscr{E}^{\circ} - \frac{RT}{nF}\ln Q$ is an unreliable equation, but it does not account well for the complexity of the system and does not apply well to alkaline batteries. Additionally it cannot explain the vertical slope of the discharge curve. What can explain the vertical slope is that once all of either zinc or manganese dioxide is consumed, there is no more matterial to react and the battery is considered fully discharged.

Answer (score 0):

A discharged battery means that cell reaction has achieved equilibrium. When this system is at equilibrium no (useful) work can be done *by* the battery. It cannot drive or pump electrons in the circuit. In other words, people say that its Gibbs free energy is zero.

Comment: I think you can improve this answer by incorporating the Nernst equation.

Comment: Good idea Zhe. I find MathJax difficult. Feel free to edit.

Comment: I don't quite feel comfortable editing to say something different, but I will add an addendum as a separate answer.

Comment: @M.Farooq You cannot rely on other's edits and avoid proper markup forever. You'll just have to bite a bullet and get to know formatting of scientific documents. This may also help you to get started with $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ when you start publishing your work. Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: Latex is good, I have heard. Somehow never needed it for my own publications. "This may also help you to get started with LATEX when you start publishing your work." andselisk, I have significant publishing experience for the last ten years :-)

Comment: I don't know how you managed *not* to use LaTeX for publications in natural sciences, but that's none of my business:) Unfortunately, you cannot ditch MathJax on Chemistry.SE. Really, MathJax isn't the hardest ting in the world, maybe you could just try adding it gradually in your answers while others fix the issues if there'll be any – it's still better than asking others to do the core writing for you:)

Comment: It depends on the field. What is your field of specialization? MS Word has a decent professional equation editor. Most of good science was also done when we had typewriters :-). LaTex is not the end of the world. I also review articles for ACS, Elsevier, Springer etc. Most articles are written in Word, and then converted into pdf. Anyway, this is just a distraction for the OP.

Comment: Mine mostly gravitates towards inorganic/solid state chemistry; to deal with publishers who are only accepting MS Word files, I'd send a pandoc'ed DOCX version, and if they are unhappy (they usually are, who would've thought), they get a PDF. It's entirely a personal choice, but I find LaTeX much more easier, cross-platform and cross-versions compatible, robust and transparent, and it rarely gets in a way.

Comment: I have heard LaTex makes good looking CVs. It is a personal choice. I know a (old) colleague who uses Excel all the time-even very complicated simulations. I told him of MATLAB but he doesn't budge. I believe science is getting all about presentation. I would love the old time where the focus was science not decoration.

Comment: @M.Farooq : A note to you also... Could you please read my comment to Zhe's answer.

Comment: @glucose, You are right, a discharged battery does not mean that the voltage is zero.

Comment: @M.Farooq : which implies that the Gibbs free energy of cell is also not zero... since the cell is in equilibrium with its surrounding... meaning the system of cell and discharger component are in equilibrium...

Comment: @glucose, I believe the story is far more complex for real batteries. A battery can be dead (as well) if the internal resistance becomes too large during the discharge process. Zhe and I were talking about the simple Cu/Zn cell. See Zhe's point as well. What do you think?

Comment: @M.Farooq : Complex batteries: agree... I do agree with Zhe's  point that 'There is no potential to push electrons through any circuit' (irrespective of surrounding)... And even your point: 'When this system is at equilibrium no (useful) work can be done by the battery. It cannot drive or pump electrons in the circuit' ... But I disagree when it comes to Gibbs free energy or potential of the particular cell reaction(caution: Not cell system ie  body + surrounding) being zero.

Comment: What is the value of Gibbs free energy at equilibrium? It is supposed to be zero because a system at equilibrium cannot do any useful work. Let us not discuss real cells which are quite complex, but what is your take with a simple Cu/Zn cell? During discharge a time will come when E will be zero. What would be the corresponding G value?

Comment: The discussion's going on great and I would really like to continue but (extremely sorry) actually I am travelling... So would continue the discussion after probably a day or two, or even at times in between...

Comment: Better to start a new thread/question once you come back. Nobody reads comments so people will miss your point of view.

Answer (score 0):

To extend @M.Farooq's answer, let's look at this a slightly different way.

From the Nernst equation:

$$\mathscr{E} = \mathscr{E}^{\circ} - \frac{RT}{nF}\ln Q$$

As the reaction progresses, the value of $Q$, the reaction quotient, increases because product concentrations are higher and reactant concentrations are lower. As a result, the cell potential $\mathscr{E}$ decreases.

When $\mathscr{E}$ reaches zero, then battery is fully discharged. There is no potential to push electrons through any circuit.

Comment: AFAIK there are only two accepted notations for the standard state: uppercase plimsoll "$^⦵$" and a circle "°". "∅" looks like an "empty set symbol" and doesn't make any sense here in this context.

Comment: I reverted to using \varnothing because there is no simple LaTeX symbol and I had various instances where the plimsoll unicode was not supported. I'll use circ instead, though to be fair, the empty set symbol (and that's what I'm using) is just a rotated plimsoll. @andselisk

Comment: May I ask you where the "⦵" Unicode symbol isn't supported? I've been using it thorough with MathJax and XeLaTeX for the past couple of years and it always worked for me just fine.

Comment: It appears as a small rectangle on this Android tablet.

Comment: @badjohn Interesting, your Android must be lacking fonts with the plimsoll symbol. Personally, I've never experienced this issue on any of the Android devices (I used AOSP since version 4 and later LineageOS), but it's good to know some vendors might cut off support for special characters.

Comment: @andselisk It's rather old.  A Samsung Galaxy Tab S SMT-700 running Android 6.0.1.

Comment: Hmm, my comment didn't post. Yeah, it doesn't show up on my Pixel book, which is one of the newer models. My windows desktop and Linux workstation are both able to show it.

Comment: @Zhe I don't think it's a hardware issue, rather a *firmware* one (poor font selection/lack of Unicode support). I installed "pure" stock Androids (often non-official builds by the community) on all of the devices I used, starting with an 8-year old Samsung Galaxy S2, and I never had any problems with missing characters or tofus. I'm quite surprised to see this sort of problems emerging on one of the latest Google's devices which costs nearly $1000 :(

Comment: Well, it didn't cost me anything, and the problem may just be that I need to install a missing font somewhere.

Comment: @Zhe : I would like to say that if a battery is discharged it **does not necessarily mean that potential of battery is zero**, it is infact a relative term wherein the potential of battery is less than or equal(in some cases may be zero also) to the potential of the (chemical) surrounding.

Comment: @glucose This is true.